# How to automatically restarts node js script when it crashes

Tags: node.js, npm

I am new to programming, but I am running a script I got off GitHub that keeps a Minecraft account in a server at all times. Sometimes, the account will get kicked which makes the script crash and then I need to manually restart it. Is there any way I can make it automatically restart when it crashes so I do not need to keep intervening?

Someone else who runs the program told me to use « npm start supervisor algasnobrakes »but this does not seem to be changing anything because it crashes the same way as it crashes when I do « npm start »
Any suggestions for something I could use to restart the script after it crashes automatically? Thank you!

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow! The best way of getting good answers is to ask questions with good quality in the first place. 
The easiest solution is to wrap your code in a ```try/catch``` block, so the script won't crash in the first place. But providing your code will help for a better answer.

Comment: @ArootinAghazaryan I just found a way to install a supevisor made for the program, thank you for the help though!

Comment: if you're looking for a nodejs specific way of doing that then I would suggest https://www.npmjs.com/package/forever or https://www.npmjs.com/package/pm2